# Basic calculator using break statements to control the logic

Tags: python, calculator

Below is a simple calculator program in which I'm using break statements to control the logic. I was wondering if this is overkill on the break statements or is it OK.

```
while True:
    try:
        print("Choose operation(+ | - | * | / | Enter 'e' to exit)")
        op=input()
        if op!="+" and op!="-" and op!="*" and op!="/" and op!="e":
            print("Invalid input, you must choose an option from the menu.")
            break
        elif op=="e":
            break
        else:
            print(">")
            val1=float(input(val1))
            print(">")
            val2=float(input(val2))
            if op=="+":
                print("= ", val1+val2)
            elif op=="-":
                print("= ", val1-val2) 
            elif op=="*":
                print("= ", val1*val2)
            else:
                print("= ", val1/val2)  
    except ValueError:  
        print("Input must be numerical.")  
        break 
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("Dividing by zero is undefined.")
        break
exit()
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Your post looks fine, hope you get some good answers!

Answer (score 2):

## Choosing an Operation

You can use a dictionary, rather than `if/elif/else` statements to choose operations more cleanly:

```py
from operator import add, sub, mul, truediv

OPERATIONS = {
    '+': add,
    '-': sub,
    '*': mul,
    '/': truediv
}

# if an operation is present
print(OPERATIONS['+'](1, 2))
3

# otherwise
print(OPERATIONS['%'](1, 2))
KeyError
```

Now, you can clean up your `if` statements, and get rid of most of your `if op ==` checks:

```py
op = input("Choose operation(+ | - | * | / | Enter 'e' to exit)\n").strip()

if op == 'e':
    print('Exiting')
    exit()

try:
    operation = OPERATIONS[op]
except KeyError:
    print(f"{op} was an invalid choice")
    break

~snip~

# This is how you'd use that operation, since it is a function
try:
    print(operation(val1, val2))
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("Can't divide by zero!")
```

## Choosing `val1` and `val2`

I think you made a typo by mistake and the argument to `input` was supposed to be `input('val1')` and `input('val2')`. Either way, I think it might be a bit cleaner to add a function here. This makes it easier to wrap up the possible `ValueErrors` that could come from generating your values on bad input:

```py
def get_input_values():
    """
    Parse numerical input into floats for calculator operations
    """
    values = []

    for i in range(2):
        print('>')
        # this gives some visual space for the user to break up
        # the prompt from the actual input
        val = float(input(f'val{i}: ')
        values.append(val)

    return value


# now you can do a try/except wrapping this function
# and unpack the result
try:
    val1, val2 = get_input_values()
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)
    exit()
```

You could even extend this to `N` values if you wanted to:

```py
def get_input_values(N=2):
    ~snip~
    for i in range(N):
        # rest of function

try:
    values = get_input_values(5)
except ValueError as e:
    ~snip~
```

## Adding a `main` function and `__name__` guard

This will help wrap your code up into a single function that can be called/looped/etc. It's cleaner and, for larger programs, makes it easier to find what runs the code. Also, an `if __name__ == "__main__"` guard allows you to import items from this code without it executing:

```py
# OPERATIONS still lives in global scope here
OPERATIONS = {
    '+': add,
    '-': sub,
    '*': mul,
    '/': truediv
}


def main():
    op = input("Choose operation(+ | - | * | / | Enter 'e' to exit)\n").strip()
   
    if op == 'e':
        print('Exiting')
        exit()

     try:
        operation = OPERATIONS[op]
     except KeyError:
        print(f"{op} was an invalid choice")
        break


     try:
         val1, val2 = get_input_values()
     except ValueError as e:
         print(e)
         exit()

     try:
         result = operation(val1, val2)
     except ZeroDivisionError:
         print("Can't divide by zero!")
         exit()
     else:
         print(result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # you can move your loop down here now
    while True:
        main()
```